# SVG Path, Is this a Cubic Bezier Curve?

Tags: svg

**This is a two-part question:**

1. Does the first code section below (produced by Adobe Illustrator) represent
   a Cubic Bezier Curve in an SVG file?
2. If so, what do each of the numbers following the lower-case Cs represent in the first  (Adobe Illustrator) example?

   **Adobe Illustrator Example:**

> `<path style="fill:none;stroke:#00FF00;stroke-width:0.5102;stroke-linecap:round; stroke-linejoin:round;" d="M223.827,404.942 c-6.741,6.32-7.083,16.908-0.762,23.649l0,0c0.184,0.201,0.561,0.577,0.762,0.762" />`

Here is part of an example from **[w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands):**

```
<path class="SamplePath" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200
                                       S400,300 400,200" />
```

In the second W3 example, I understand the numbers following the 'M' refer to the starting x,y coordinates and that the upper case 'C's indicate absolute positioning. The pattern seems fairly obvious *in the W3 example* regarding the groupings of XYs.  However, I don't know what to make of the Adobe Illustrator example with the groups seperated by a negative sign and no comma, e.g.,: `16.908-0.762`. **How are the numbered sequences that follow the lower-case Cs in the Adobe Illustrator example parsed and grouped, and what do each of those numbers represent in the first (Adobe Illustrator) example?**

Comment: The first code block could use editing. I had to remove the first character ('<') just to get the block to show up, and it still does not have a gray background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to 1 is yes.

As for 2...

In the path syntax spaces and commas are optional. 16.908-0.762 is parsed one character at a time so the parser must know that when it gets to the - sign that 16.908 is a number but 16.908- is not and therefore the - sign must be the beginning of the next number which is -0.762

There are three pairs of numbers in the illustrator example. Adding optional spaces makes it clearer...

c -6.741,6.32 -7.083,16.908 -0.762,23.649

The grammar is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF)

Comment: Thank you for this clarification.  If you have a moment, I also have odd quantities of numbers that end in zero e.g., "c6.32-6.742,5.979-17.33-0.762-23.65l0,0". I am guessing that the last trailing zero implies (0,0). Is that correct?

Comment: You mean that last bit. That's a lower case l (the letter that follows k) followed by 0,0 isn't it?

Comment: Hmmm. Firstly, thanks again, I see now that 2nd to last zero is grouped with the last zero (i.e.,(0,0)). However, I'm *guessing that the character before it is a lower-case 'L' which stands for 'lineto'. I had mistaken it for the number one, but when I copy and pasted it, it looks like a lower-case 'L'.